# How to add source files as external dependency in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build

I downloaded glad OpenGL loader. However it only includes source and header files. I add header files to include directory in visual studio. How can I add cpp files without adding my current project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the library first, before you can link against it. So, first build the library you've downloaded, then add the .lib to the linker libraries.